Django error while creating the blog web application
urls.py
path("blogpost/<int:id>", views.blogpost, name="blogpost)

views.py
def blogpost(request, id):
    post = Blog1.objects.filter(post_id = id)[0]
    return render(request, 'blogpost.html', {'post':post})

I'm having an error that the Blog1 object is iterable.
I tried everything, and my model has been created as well for blog1, and the primary key has issues under post_id, but I don't know why I am having this error about the object is iterabl. Any idea??

It is useful to use the get_object_or_404 function when trying to import a single object.
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog1

def blogpost(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog1, id=id)
    return render(request, 'blogpost.html', {'post':post})

Please refer to this article.

Yes !! it worked actually. Thank you so much

i think you want this...?
def blogpost(request, id):
    post = Blog1.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'blogpost.html', {'post':post})


But, I have declared post_id as my primary key so it should be post_id = id ??

where is models.py?

or try this. post = Blog1.objects.filter(post_id = id).first()

When you are trying to declare single object always use get_object_or_404 in django.
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog1
def blogpost(request, id):
post = get_object_or_404(Blog1, id=id)
return render(request, 'blogpost.html', {'post':post})
It worked for me and useful for others as well.
